# What is the best Latin translation for "Love and intellect will prevail"?

Tags: sentence-translation

How do we say " Love and intellect will prevail" in Latin? Thank you very much for your time. I mean love and prevail as a subject noun phrase. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi Burcu, and welcome to the site! Could you supply some more context, and more details about what exactly you want to convey? "Love" can mean a lot of things in English, and that affects the Latin translation.

Answer (score 2):

**'Vincent amor ratioque.'**

means (word by word) *vincent* -they will conquer; *amor* -love; *ratio-que* - and-rationality, and-reason, and-good sense. ( *-que* is 'and').
'Love and reason will prevail.'

Answer (score 2):

"Ama ut ratio vincat."

Of course, that's if "Love" was a verb in English.

Also possible, "Ama et tunc intellectus vincet", but it feels weird to coordinate an indicative with an imperative, and it does feel like "conquer" is logically subordinate.

"Intellectus" may be the best noun, rather than "ratio".  For example, compare "intellectus agens" as a technical phrase.

Comment: İf I use intellectus as the noun will it take "que" again as in "ratioque" to give the meaning "and"?